# Are these Search customizations possible in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, sharepoint-search, customization

Our client wishes to have these customizations:

1) search text box in both places, on the page and on Office 365 bar

2) page numbers on top and bottom

Are these passible?

Answer (score 1):

1) It is not possible to keep both OOB search boxes in SharePoint Online. With [launch of new enterprise search experience](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/roadmap?ms.url=roadmap&rtc=1&filters=&searchterms=34273) (Microsoft Search) feature, the original search boxes on pages will no longer be available.

2) It is currently not supported to customize Microsoft Search, but you can customize the classic search result page to display page numbers on top and bottom.

Reference:
[Differences between the classic and modern search experiences in SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search)

Comment: Will we be able to keep using classic search to have the search box on the page?

Comment: @joseluisgonzalezclua I cannot be sure, but if you have enabled targeted release in your tenant then no, I do not think this change can be withdrawn. You will still have classic search experience in SPO though, including global search center and classic search box on all classic pages.